# kali linux dual booting installation

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning

I have 40 GB of unallocated free space and I used win32 disk imager to write ISO file to my USB.

While dual booting Kali with Windows 10, in the disk partition section it doesn't seem to show me the 40 GB I have but only the 12 GB that win32 had made.

[image: Windows view of the disk]
[image: Kali Linux view of the disk]

Answer (score -1):

That's because those are two separated logical drives. To get Windows 10 to "see" the 40gb partition, you need to set a mounting point or a drive letter.

Comment: so ,do I need to make that 40gb free space into a drive ?
if yes then the tutorial I am following to do so doesn't do that and I don't know how to use that drive in the partitioning

Comment: @satvikkaul or merge it into other partition

Comment: I did what you said ie to set a mounting point to the 40gb free space but it doesn't show anything this time too ,please help @dmb

Comment: @satvikkaul This is incorrect. Please read the comment below your question. the dynamic disk is the problem (and there's no easy solution other than reformatting the whole drive and keep it as "basic"). Dynamic drive isn't good (not compatible) with dual-boot.

Comment: so basically what youre implying is the I cant dual boot unless I reformat my whole hard drive and then convert it to basic drive? @GabrielaGarcia

Comment: As long as it's dynamic the installer won't recognize the unused space. And formatting will be enough because basic is the default.

Comment: I am buying a new external hard drive to back up this data and  I will be updating you all on the same , thankyou!